# Hibernate ObjectNotFoundException, even if records are present in table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC app in which there are two model classes: LocationModel and ContactModel. Below is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contact")
public class ContactModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="contactid")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int contactId;

    @Column(name="contactname")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name="contactemail")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="contactphone")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="locationid")
    private LocationModel locationModel;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Location")
public class LocationModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="locationid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private int locationId;

    @Column(name="locationname")
    private String locationName;

    @Column(name="locationdesc")
    private String locationDescription;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String locationType;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name="circle")
    private int circle;

    @Column(name="district")
    private int district;

    @Column(name="town")
    private int town;

    @Column(name="lattitude")
    private String lattitude;

    @Column(name="longitude")
    private String longitude;

    @Column(name="locationuid")
    private String locationUID;

    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name="bedcount")
    private int bedCount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "locationModel", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ContactModel> contactList;
}
```

Primary key in location table is foreign key in contact table. I have 2 records in contact table, with location id 0.

I am using following code for getting contact list:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session
                    .createQuery("from ContactModel where contactName like :contactName");
            return query.setParameter("contactName", contactName + "%").list();
```

But it shows exception:

```
Error performing load command : org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bizmerlin.scm.model.LocationModel#0]
17:03:31,135 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-2) org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bizmerlin.scm.model.LocationModel#0]

17:03:31,139 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-2)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:247)

17:03:31,141 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:214)

17:03:31,143 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-9090-2)    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:264)
```

Perhaps it is due to that fact that location table has no record with location id 0. If so, how can I get contact list, even if their location is null?

Answer (score 0):

Use **optional** attribute

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="locationid")
private LocationModel locationModel;
```

http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2011/12/one-to-many-assocition-that-is-optional.html